# How to set R to show console prompt on update.packages()?

Tags: r, linux

When I start R in the console of my machine (R version 4.3.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) and run `update.packages()`, a popup prompts me to select a CRAN mirror.

[image]

Conversely, when I `ssh` in our server (R version 4.3.1 on AlmaLinux 9.2), I get the console prompt which I like much better.

```
> update.packages(ask=FALSE)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Secure CRAN mirrors 

 1: 0-Cloud [https]
 2: Australia (Canberra) [https]
 3: Australia (Melbourne 1) [https]
 ...
75: United Arab Emirates [https]
76: Uruguay [https]
77: (other mirrors)

Selection:
```

How can I set R on my machine to display the console prompt? Note that I do not want to set a default server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by the `menu.graphics` option.

> menu.graphics:
> Logical: should graphical menus be used if available?.
> Defaults to TRUE. Currently applies to select.list, chooseCRANmirror,
> setRepositories and to select from multiple (text) help files in help.

```
options(menu.graphics = FALSE)

update.packages()

--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Secure CRAN mirrors

 1: 0-Cloud [https]
 2: Australia (Canberra) [https]
 3: Australia (Melbourne 1) [https]
 ...
75: United Arab Emirates [https]
76: Uruguay [https]
77: (other mirrors)
```

To permanently default to text menus for the above functions, edit it into your `.Rprofile` file.

Comment: Works, and `x11()` still open. Since my `.Rprofile` didn't exist I created it using `touch ~/.Rprofile && nano ~/.Rprofile`. I noticed I tried something similar before but I used `/etc/R/Rprofile.site` instead which is wrong. Moving respective lines to `~/.Rprofile` finally did the trick (not in `R --vanilla` though)!